# Replacement of UIPicker Control in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

please suggest an exact or a near replacement for a UIPicker Control(that we have in iOS) in WP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LoopingSelector control in the windows phone toolkit.